# gson,fromJson returning null. Android

Tags: android, json, nullpointerexception, gson

I'm really stuck on this, after searching for a long time.
I have a Json string which is called response.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
SearchResult searchResult = gson.fromJson(response, SearchResult.class);
```

searchResult is always null.

Here is the SearchResult class:

```
public class SearchResult implements Serializable{


public SearchResult() {
    }


    private List<MyMarkerResponse> myMarkersList;

    public List<MyMarkerResponse> getSearch() {
        return myMarkersList;
    }

    public void setSearch(List<MyMarkerResponse> search) {
        myMarkersList = search;
    }
```

Here is the json response:

```
{"myMarkerList":[{"notes":"now","_id":5096363633147904,"latitude":51.52753303816573,"longitude":-0.15742387622594833,"title":"home"},{"notes":"","_id":5137355874762752,"latitude":51.46299731478184,"longitude":-0.015837103128433228,"title":""},{"notes":"","_id":5167132077719552,"latitude":44.890621596087136,"longitude":42.57036656141281,"title":"cat"},{"notes":"new place","_id":5631986051842048,"latitude":65.7773746361831,"longitude":107.60726854205132,"title":"hello"},{"notes":"new place","_id":5692462144159744,"latitude":65.7773746361831,"longitude":107.60726854205132,"title":"hello"},{"notes":"","_id":5720147234914304,"latitude":51.51407752981666,"longitude":-0.12392342090606688,"title":""},{"notes":"place","_id":5730082031140864,"latitude":61.10287229393116,"longitude":88.51000271737576,"title":"new"},{"notes":"","_id":5749328048029696,"latitude":23.44142818293187,"longitude":20.003406554460526,"title":""},{"notes":"now","_id":5769015641243648,"latitude":51.52753303816573,"longitude":-0.15742387622594833,"title":"home"}]}
```

Here is MyMarkerResponse class:

```
public class MyMarkerResponse implements Serializable{

public MyMarkerResponse() {
}    

    private String notes;

    private Long _id;

    private double latitude;

    private double longitude;

    private String title;

    public Long get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public void set_id(Long _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getNotes() {
        return notes;
    }

    public void setNotes(String notes) {
        this.notes = notes;
    }




}
```

When i call searchResult.getSearch() i get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object reference
```

If you could help, please!!

Comment: simple typoe -> close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've misspelled `myMarkerList` in the POJO.  Currently you have:

```
private List<MyMarkerResponse> myMarkersList;
```

Check your spelling (remove the 's').

Comment: Thanks. It was the spelling! Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

Your `SearchResult` POJO is not correct for the JSON that you expect to deserialize. Specifically, the main JSON object contains just one property/attribute/key called "`myMarkerList`". So your POJO should likewise contain one property of type list/array. You need to change it into:

```
public class SearchResult {

    private List<MyMarkerResponse> myMarkerList;

    public List<MyMarkerResponse> getSearch() {
        return myMarkerList;
    }

    public void setSearch(List<MyMarkerResponse> search) {
        Search = myMarkerList;
    }
}
```

**UPDATED:**
I realized that the code itself is correct, you just need to use a different `fromJson` function (the one that takes the `Type` as second parameter):

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type searchResultType = new TypeToken<SearchResult>() {}.getType();
SearchResult searchResult = gson.fromJson(response, searchResultType);
```

Then you code should work as you expected.
Please give it a try and let me know if this helps.

Comment: This didn't work. This is the same code as I have, only you changed the name of the List to myMarkerList (and not Search). Still not working, thanks

Comment: This is odd, could you please make your `SearchResult` and `MyMarkerResponse` to implements `Serializable`, also add no-args constructor - like : `public SearchResult(){}` and `public MyMarkerResponse(){}`.

Comment: The one thing I can think of now is to use `ArrayList` instead of just `List` as the type for `myMarkerList`. Also, please put your updated code so that we can see how the changes were applied.

Comment: Thanks for the edits. So `response` is a `String` not a `JSON` object? I will try and reproduce this on my side. Maybe we are missing something...

Comment: Hi, I managed to solve this on my side - I had to use the method signature: `fromJson(String json, Type typeOfT)`. Please try the suggestion and accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

My friend use this site : [JSON schema to POJO](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

If you using `Gson`in POJO you need annotations.

Select Source type : **JSON** and Annotation Style **Gson**

Paste your example Json response and generate it .